# Show SQL query of controller

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am using cakephp v3.x and mysql.

I would like to see the SQL query of a controller. There is no error with this controller and it runs successfully.

```
public function appGetResult()
{
    $this->autoRender = false;
    $start_date = $this->request->query['start_date'];
    $end_date = $this->request->query['end_date']; 

    $results = $this->MonthlyReports->getResult($start_date, $end_date);

    echo json_encode($results);
}
```

How to modify the controller code to display the SQL query used in generating the results? This is not for actual production use. More for examination.

Comment: May I ask why the negative vote? Please explain so that I can improve on my future questions. THanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn on query logging on CakePHP3: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#query-logging

If you're interested in doing more debugging and such, [DebugKit](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/debug-kit.html) does an amazing job.

Comment: Thanks. I am still somewhat at a loss. How does one get the `$conn` in `$conn->logQueries(true);`? Where do I run this code?

Comment: This should do it: `$conn = ConnectionManager::get('connection_name');`. Insert your *connection_name* from the config.

Comment: In which file should I run this line `$conn = ConnectionManager::get('connection_name');`? In the controller?

Comment: Yes. I would run it just above the query you want to log, before the *logQueries(true)*.

Comment: Don't forget to add `use Cake\Datasource\ConnectionManager;` at the top of your controller.

Comment: Sorry, how do I know what `connection_name` to use? Where do I get this information? From which config?

Comment: It's in the [database config](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#database-configuration). You can see 'default' in the link as the array index.

Comment: A follow-up question was asked. Answer is correct but the log file was not found.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33629642/where-is-the-log-file-after-enabling-query-logging

Answer (score 1):

I figured out an indirect way for an answer to my own question. This is an indirect way to see the MySQL query statements.

```
public function appGetResult()
{
    //$this->autoRender = false;
    $start_date = $this->request->query['start_date'];
    $end_date = $this->request->query['end_date']; 

    $results = $this->MonthlyReports->getResult($start_date, $end_date);

    echo json_encode($results);
}
```

By commenting away `$this->autoRender = false;` and not having a view .ctp, the php page stops with an error. The DebugKit panel will be shown on the erroneous webpage. From the DebugKit panel, one will be able to see the SQL statements.

Comment: Cool. how silly way :D. cakephp 3.x it self has it's on debugging tool (called DebigKit). I fyo have it enabled then you would have the debugKit toolbar at the footer of the page. Click "Sql Log" button it shows you all the queries that runs on that time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use getLog() or showLog() function to do it

```
var_dump($this->MonthlyReports->getDataSource()->getLog(false, false));
var_dump($this->MonthlyReports->getDataSource()->showLog());
```

Comment: I think this answer is about cakephp 2.x and the quiestion is about cakephp 3.x