# Where is the log file after enabling query logging?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, logging, cakephp-3.0

I followed the instructions to enable query logging in cakephp v3.

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#query-logging

```
// Turn query logging on.
$conn->logQueries(true);

// Turn query logging off
$conn->logQueries(false);

use Cake\Log\Log;

// Console logging
Log::config('queries', [
    'className' => 'Console',
    'stream' => 'php://stderr',
    'scopes' => ['queriesLog']
]);

// File logging
Log::config('queries', [
    'className' => 'File',
    'path' => LOGS,
    'file' => 'queries.log',
    'scopes' => ['queriesLog']
]);
```

After enabling query logging, I am not able to find the log file. I looked under the logs folder. I don't see any `queries.log`. Where can the log file be found?

Comment: It is kind of rude to just create a different question without accepting the previous one. Anyways. Check your error.log, you might have errors. Do you have permissions to create the log file?

Comment: Sorry about that. I still have not found the answer. Yes, I have the permissions because I see other log files like debug.log being updated.

Comment: What if you try logging it to your debug.log file? Does that work?

Comment: Great idea! Will do that now.

Comment: No, it does not work. No error in the error.log as well.

Comment: Thanks for your patience in helping anyway.

Comment: @Satisfaction, Accepted the answer for the previous question.

Comment: I'll get back to you when I set up and test a clean installation myself.

Comment: Thank you very much. Most kind of you to help a stranger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've created a test project. Created a simple model so I can parse the data.

In the controller, I added these namespaces:

```
use App\Model\Table\User; // <---My model
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
use Cake\Log\Log;
use Cake\Datasource\ConnectionManager;
```

Here's the basic data parse in a controller:

```
    $conn = ConnectionManager::get('default');
    Log::config('queries', [
        'className' => 'File',
        'path' => LOGS,
        'file' => 'queries.log',
        'scopes' => ['queriesLog']
    ]);

    $users = TableRegistry::get('User'); 

    $conn->logQueries(true);
    $q = $users->find('all');
    $results = $q->all();
    $conn->logQueries(false);
```

All of this works just great.

Comment: Thanks for your patient help. I followed your answer but still could not see the log file. I must have done something careless without knowing what it is. Thankfully, I figured out an indirect way to see the SQL statement. See answer below :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33628161/show-sql-query-of-controller/33631951#33631951

Answer (score 0):

Log also should be enabled in datasources config by specify `'log' => true`:

```
'Datasources' => [
    'default' => [
        'className' => Connection::class,
        'driver' => Mysql::class,
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        ...
        'log' => true,
        ...
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL', null),
    ],
```